# Scrapy select id with wildcard

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and Python and i am trying to make a spider to scrap prices from a magento site. The spider is working fine on non-magento sites, but when it comes to magento I can get product name and availability but I can't get the price because magento assigns a different id to the class.

Below is the relevant html from the magento site:

```
<span class="price" id="price-including-tax-1722">
```

18,60 €

I have tried `[starts-with(@class,"price-including-tax-")]` and many other options, but none seem to work.

How can I use a wildcard so that I can select the id `price-including-tax-****`?

Comment: Should that be `[starts-with(@id, "price-including-tax-")]`

Comment: @Ilayaraja I feel so stupid now!!! Thanks mate! Now i got it.. I was wildcarding class not id

Answer (score 3):

You can try the css

```
span[id*='price-including-tax']
```

or xpath

```
//span[starts-with(@id,"price-including-tax-")]
```

Do remember that a XPath won't work if you don't specify a tag (or you need to use *, which should be avoided)